# Import MySQL table from a textfile to a remote host with compression

Tags: mysql

I can import `data.sql` onto my foreign host with this command:

```
mysql -u username -p -h foreign-host.example.org -A DATA-BASE-NAME < data.sql
```

Which works fine for small export files, but I cannot find an explanation how to import a large file, so the transfer will be compressed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `--compress` flag.

```
mysql --compress -u username ...
```

> `--compress, -C`
>
> Compress all information sent between the client and the server if both support compression.
>
> http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_compress

Virtually any MySQL client and server *will* support compression.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `gunzip`:

Example:

`gunzip < path_to_gzippedfile | mysql -u username -p -h hostname database_name`.

Comment: but that would not send it compressed, which was the question